# Separate data by date in numpy calculations

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I want to run a calculation over a dataset per day
this is the csv file:
[image]

The holteandtalley package needs numpy values and in doing so it seems  to ignore that dates are a thing. What would work in considering dates? How is this possible with the conversion to numpy values??? Would it be a for loop with for 1/1/2015 -> 1/2/2015?

```
data = '''Date_minute   pressure_minute temperature_minute  _salinity_minute    density_minute
 1/1/2015 1:00  190.7204494 4.404067416 34.91503019 1028.562223
1/1/2015 1:03   226.7342222 4.380520556 34.9135466  1028.730406
1/1/2015 1:06   275.7265    4.362583889 34.91181953 1028.95763
1/2/2015 19:36  2509.618056 2.28284 34.88852093 1039.350304
1/2/2015 19:39  2541.392889 2.150881111 34.8855637  1039.508935
1/2/2015 19:42  2564.401333 1.961558889 34.88407401 1039.637896
1/2/2015 19:45  2589.747    1.865299444 34.88299396 1039.763993
1/2/2015 19:48  2605.054929 1.83268 34.88257996 1039.836633
1/3/2015 13:00  2600.003539 2.152193258 34.88413074 1039.76865
1/3/2015 13:03  2564.831611 2.343941111 34.88770727 1039.586481
1/3/2015 13:06  2516.2825   2.562826111 34.89977395 1039.347239
1/3/2015 13:09  2467.989611 2.644409444 34.90447681 1039.123766
1/3/2015 13:12  2419.898056 2.702593889 34.90656564 1038.902537
1/3/2015 13:15  2372.020838 2.764951955 34.90882427 1038.681659'''
```

e Above repersents a small sample of data copied from the  csv file. I have 3 minute averaged data and it's a lot.

but the goal is to have this h calculation done per day then save it to a csv file!

```
from holteandtalley import HolteAndTalley
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.read_csv('.csv', sep=",", index_col=None)
df = df.dropna() 
pressures = df['pressure_minute'].to_numpy()
temperatures = df['temperature_minute'].to_numpy()
salinities = df['practical_salinity_minute'].to_numpy()
densities = df['density_minute'].to_numpy()

h = HolteAndTalley(pressures,temperatures)
h.tempMLD
```

[image]

Comment: please don't include images. Copy and paste the data into your StackOverflow quesiton.

Comment: Ah there is a lot of data. I converted to a text file and pasted data = '''xxxx''' for an example. That makes sense to see it but the original data is going to be comma seprated.

Answer (score 0):

What if you change the format of the date into an integer with `df['data'] = df['data'].strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M').astype(int)`? If your data is not not in pandas datetime format, then you will also need the first line of code with: `df['data'] = pd.to_datetime(df['data'], dayfirst=True)`

```
df['data'] = pd.to_datetime(df['data'], dayfirst=True)
df['data'] = df['data'].strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M').astype(int)
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you don't have to convert it to `numpy`, but you have to convert `Pandas Series` to `list`. [The source code](https://github.com/garrettdreyfus/python-holteandtalley/blob/master/holteandtalley/tempProfile.py)  shows that the incoming parameter is converted by `asarray`.